# I need help whit a regex for username and password validation

Tags: php, regex

To implement a registration system I need a regex for username and password validation.

I want the username to only allows these characters:

- a-z
- A-Z
- 0-9
- . : - _ @

The password validation is a bit different. I want to allow all characters, but it needs to have at least one of these characters (for security):

- a-z
- A-Z
- 0-9

How do I put together these regexes?

Comment: What have you already tried?  - A Google search for "password regex" brings up a number of likely links, you may have to convert the regex syntax from one to work for PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
username: ^[a-zA-Z0-9.:_@-]+$
password: ^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]).*$
```

the password uses a passitive lookahead assertion to find a valid charcter, and if it finds one, will match the entire password.